# What are the technologies I need to know to create Gantt chart?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gantt-chart

I want to create my own Gantt chart using
 C# & ASP .net MVC

So I need to know what are other technologies required for this task.

Comment: This task solving just by using plain HTML+JS+CSS frontend techs advanced level. Using C# only for this task is a mistake, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't think it is a nice idea to develop a Gantt Chart on server side. Perhaps, not possible as it is more related to the client side. However, I would suggest you to take a look at the Javascript plugin called [HighCharts](https://www.highcharts.com/gantt/demo). I've used it and it is awesome!

Hope, this helps!